# How to speed up sql with GROUP BY and WHERE?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, group-by

I know that using index could optimize SQL with `GROUP BY` or `WHERE` clause. But how to optimize SQL with `GROUP BY` and `WHERE`? Please see my case.

I have a table to store traffic data and use it to draw a network traffic topology. Below is the table structure :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data`;

CREATE TABLE `data` 
(
    `sip` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
    `dip` varbinary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
    `app` char(96) DEFAULT NULL,
    `up` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `down` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `dtime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    KEY `dtime` (`dtime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And create index on column `dtime`.

The simplified SQL is

```
SELECT
    INET6_NTOA(sip),
    INET6_NTOA(dip),
    app,
    sum(up) AS up,
    sum(down) AS down
FROM
    `data`
WHERE
    `data`.dtime > FROM_UNIXTIME(1583031879)
AND `data`.dtime < FROM_UNIXTIME(1585537477)
GROUP BY
    sip,
    dip,
    app
```

The table can store about 10,000,000 records for one month and our requirement is to draw a network traffic topology with granularity for Last 30 days, Last 24 hours, Last 1 hour.

Obviously the index `dtime` is helpful to query data for last 1 hour or last 24 hours. But when query for last 30 days, it's a full table scan.

In extreme case, querying for 24 hours costs 5s, which is acceptable, while querying for 30 days costs 60s+ which is hard to accept.

Create index for sip,dip,app ? Seems not helpful, for I have to filter data by dtime at first. I googled the various indexing solutions, which may not suit for me.

Any ideas to speed up my SQL ? Or Any ideas to improve table design ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, a "range" in the `WHERE` prevents having the index being useful for the `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.  You could add `INDEX(sip, dip, app)` to give the Optimizer a choice.

Every table needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Perhaps it could be `PRIMARY KEY(sip, dip, app)`?  Or just `(sip, dip)`?  Note, making this the PK would be better than a simple `INDEX`.

But the real performance gain for those reports would be to build and maintain a "summary table" with a granularity of 1 hour.  One hour would let you efficiently get hour, day, month, etc.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables  And, because the summary table would be so much smaller, it won't matter when it needs a table scan.

Are the `VARBINARY(16)` some form hash?  Or a pair of IP addresses?  If they are fixed-length, consider `CHAR(16)`.

How big can `up` and `down` be?  Perhaps you don't need 8-byte `BIGINT`?  (Saving space would help performance some.

MySQL uses only one index per `SELECT`.  The Optimizer looks at each index (including the `PRIMARY KEY`) to estimate which *one* would be best.  In your case, it would weigh the choice between using `INDEX(dtime)` for filtering versus using `INDEX(sip,dip,app)` to avoid sorting.

If the `WHERE` clause filters down to very few rows; the `dtime` index would be better, and the Optimizer would *probably* use it.  And vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
1. Do you mean `INDEX(sip,dip,app)` will not work when use `INDEX(dtime)` ?
2. I should compare the optimizer effect to choose one of `INDEX(sip,dip,app)` and `INDEX(dtime)`
3. Neither `(sip,dip,app)` nor `INDEX(sip,dip)` is the primary key unfortunately. This table records app traffic from source IP to destination IP. The possible primary key is `(sip,dip,app,dtime)`. In such case, the PK index seems no effect for `where` and `groupby`.
4. `VARBINARY(16)` is used to store IPV6 address.
5. About 8-byte BIGINT tip, thanks again.

Comment: @Does - I added some more.

Answer (score 0):

could you try to use an index(sip, dip, app)(3 columns index)? I would think this may be helpful.

Comment: When only create index on (sip,dip,app), it costs terrible 4000s+. When create index on (dtime) and (sip,dip,app), it costs 60s+.  Could you please explain why is an index(sip,dip,app) helpful ?

Comment: You should use 2 indexes for dtime and (sip, dip, app) absolutely. Composite index (sip, dip, app) is related to MySQL GroupBy processing logic. [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html]

Comment: _If_ the optimizer chooses to use `(sip,dip,app)`, then it can avoid the sort.  If that is the `PRIMARY KEY`, other details help speed it up.